# How to restrict LAN addresses in a browser?

Tags: web-browser, chrome

How to prevent Chrome to connect addresses from LAN to prevent CSRF attacks like this?

`<img src="http://192.168.0.1/some_action">`

Info for other browsers is welcome here too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable the Chrome flag Block insecure private network requests.

chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests

[image: Block insecure private network requests]

Comment: Wow! There is already a flag for it. What does "default" value mean?